# Jenkins error handling: using try/catch to post to log after build is complete and checked for errors

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have another question about Pipelines this time about error handling using try/catch. What I am doing is using the "try" outside the stage so I can easily tell which stages failed and which passed. And this has worked brilliantly.

I need to now worry about logging and success/failure for all our logs. So here is my dilemma: I want to it build (try) then error check (catch) then output SUCCESS if it has built and checked for errors. If the error check (catch) catches errors, then output to log FAILURE. I am sure the solution is staring at me in the face and I am missing it. This is what I have (simple version) that is not very elegant:

```
env.STAGE_STATUS = ""
try {
    stage ('Build Setup') {
        echo "Did this work?"
    }
} catch (errors) {
    echo "This did not work!"
    env.STAGE_STATUS = "FAIL"
}
if ("%STAGE_STATUS%" != "FAIL") {
    echo "This did work!"
}
```

As always thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Using try/catch/finally inside stage looks more elegant and at least more readable. Secondary if you want to fail build (which is basically same cause in your sample you are failing stage, which is also failing the job itself) use following var `currentBuild.result`, which is btw globally accessible. Saying so, I would go for this code:

```
stage('Build Setup') {
   try {
       echo 'Did this work?'
   } catch {
       echo 'This did not work!'
       currentBuild.result = 'FAILED'
   } finally {
       if (currentBuild.result != 'FAILED') {
           echo 'This did work!'
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I do understand that putting the try/catch inside is the preferred method and just looks better for readability. However I need to be able to fail a stage not necessarily the entire build. This was what I found out there and works the way I need it. I just want to be able to try, catch and if pass and no errors, then output to the appropriate log files. My overall goal is to move from an existing system, but some things I cannot change.